# Reading DateTime saved in UTC from T-Sql database in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, datetime, utc

I'm saving datetime in t-sql db as UTC and not local time i.e after saving, it loses that it is UTC date ex: `2011-11-08 00:00:00.000`. While reading from db in C#, it's read as local time and not UTC. ex: after reading the dateTime value, a `dateTime.ToUniversalTime()` gives a different value.

How do I read the db datetime value as UTC and not local time? Or I should saved in local time in t-sql?

Comment: What do you get if you check `dateTime.Kind`? It may be `Unspecified`...

Comment: `dateTime.Kind` is `Unspecified`

Comment: What does the insert (or update) query that saves this datetime look like?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Okay, if you're getting a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Unspecified`, you can just use:

```
DateTime utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(unspecified, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

This sort of problem is just one of the [reasons I dislike `DateTime`](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).

Comment: i do not like the fact that when a utc datetime value is saved in tsql db the timezone info is lost and it's read as local time.

Comment: @hIpPy: No, it's a pain - but that's a problem with the database types, basically. You could use `DateTimeOffset` if your database supports it.

Comment: It helped solve the issue with timezone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096772/450913) didn't work for me. For some reason `DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc)` returns a DateTime object of `Unspecified` kind.

Following worked, however:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-07 00:15:2.663"); // Assuming UTC, Kind=Unspecified
date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.Utc); // Assuming UTC, Kind=Utc
var output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date); // "2017-03-07T00:15:02.663Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Property `Kind` Can be: Local, UTC, Unspecified. If you just initialize a new DateTime object, the `Kind` is default set to Local.

```
// read exact same time from DB, but leave the 'Kind' to be Unspecified
// PS Kind is not local, not utc here
(DateTime)(reader["dbdate"]) 

// read exact same time from DB, but set 'Kind' to be UTC
// if your date in your DB is also utc time, then use this one
DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)(reader["dbdate"]), DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Comment: "If you just initialize a new DateTime object, the Kind is default set to Local." No, the default is Unspecified.